# Custom windowed operator in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to implement next formula: Si = (x1 - w1) + ... + (xn - wn) like a Conv=x1*w1 + ... xn*wn for some area under X (input tensor) and kernel W. Important that this operation repeat on all areas X with slice W with stride and padding params like a simple convolution.

How do this?

I found similar question a while ago on stackoverflow. But it finished on custom implementation on C++ and compilation or changes CUDA source or something like that.

Is there an easier way today?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly then you compute `Si=(x1 + ... + xn)-(w1 + ... + wn)`? The sum of the weights is a single number, so you don't have a "Kernel" anymore. The first sum you can compute via `tf.nn.conv2d` and a filter that is initialized with `tf.ones`. But I don't think that's what you meant to do, so could you maybe specify your question further?

Comment: You mean next algorithm?

1) tf.conv2d(X, Ones)

2) tf.subtract(X, W) 

But W and X have different size. X have shape (100, 100, 3) for example, it's just a input image. But W have shape (3,3,3) because it's like conv kernel.

Comment: @CyberDreamer As I tried to show in my answer, in the operation you are trying to implement, your kernel collapses to a single number. So you can just sum it up to be a scalar and subtract it. Tensorflow will take care of broadcasting your scalar to the `(100,100,3)` entries of `X`.